# vim | remove first few lines from a 700MB file

Tags: vim, text-editor

How do I quickly scrape off first few lines from a large file, without opening the whole file in main memory?

---

### UPDATE

I do not want to pipe the starting `x` lines into another file and then cut the first few lines, I want to update the original file.

Comment: If Darcara's answer isnt what you're looking for, then why do you have that marked 'correct' and effectively 'closed' this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly vim, but to cut of the first 10 lines you could use

```
tail --lines=+10 somefile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: The command will not pipe the first x lines, but all lines starting with the 10th to a new file. After that, just rename the file to overwrite the original.

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -n+11 somefile.txt | vim -
```

To chop off the first 10* lines and open the file for edit, without creating a temporary file. Note that the file will have no name in vim when you open it this way. That's the only drawback.

* Note that although I used 11 in the command, this *starts* from line 11. So it will chop off the first 10 lines.

Answer (score 3):

The original question was never actually answered here.  I believe this is a solution:

```
sed -i 's/`head -n 500 foo.txt`//' foo.txt
```

This would eliminate the first 500 lines of a file without having to create a temporary file.  (Actually, you might have to do head -n 499)  I think it's actually quite useful as a one-liner for say, cleaning up log files, without just erasing the entire log.

Comment: Very unnecessary to do a match/replace. I even think it'll break if you have slashes in those 500 lines. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 1 502 > foo.txt
$ sed -i 1,500d foo.txt 
$ cat foo.txt 
501
502
```

Answer (score 0):

vim will always want/need to read in the whole file, so there's no way to do it using (only) vim. Darcara's suggestion looks good.

This process will always involve copying all but the first part of the file to another, so I don't see any way of doing it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you can do with the file you may be better of using `sed` or `awk` for editing such a big file.

Answer (score 0):

How about ..

1. split the original file into 2 parts. (`p1`: lines 0 - `x`) (`p2`: lines `x+1` - `n`)
2. edit `p1` since you want to edit the first `x` lines. We'll call it `p1'`
3. combine `p1'` and `p2`

*In short*

1. `file` -> `p1` and `p2`
2. `p1` -> `p1'`
3. `p1'` + `p2` -> `new_file`

**Commands**

1. use `split` or `cut`
2. use `vim` or editor of your choice.
3. use `cat` to combine